# Nifi- MergeContent processor- Mergestrategy

Tags: apache-nifi, data-ingestion

what is the difference between Bin Packing algorithm and defragment merge strategy in merge content processor nifi any comparison regarding performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bin packing is the standard strategy that is used when merging together data, it just writes the bytes of each flow file one after another, inserting optional header, footer, and demarcators.

Defragment strategy is for when you have previously used one of the "split" processors and want to undo the split back to a single flow file. This mode requires that all of the incoming flow files have the standard "fragment" attributes like fragment.identifier, fragment.index, and fragment.count which are created by the split processors.

Comment: Does the correlation attribute name property work for both types or just the bin packing type?

Comment: Correlation attribute wouldn't be used for defragment strategy because the incoming flow files will already be correlated by their fragment.identifier from the split.